# Doxygen fail to detect NS_ENUM in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, doxygen, nsenumerator

I'm using Doxygen to document API written in Objective-C.
Doyxygen fail to understand NS_ENUM typedef.

I've found this solution but it did not work for me.

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES 
MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES 
EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES 
PREDEFINED             = NS_ENUM(x,y)=y 

Regards, 
  Dimitri
```

This is my input file:

```
/**
 *  Represent the possible states.
 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, ABEnumType)
{
    /**
     *  State A.
     */
    StateA = 0,
    /**
     *  State B.
     */
    StateB
};
```

This is the output I get:

```
Preprocessing /src/ABEnumType.h...
error: /src/ABEnumType.h:17:17: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations [clang]
error: /src/ABEnumType.h:17:28: error: unknown type name 'ABEnumType' [clang]
error: /src/ABEnumType.h:18:1: error: function definition is not allowed here [clang]
error: /src/ABEnumType.h:17:9: error: C++ requires a type specifier for all declarations [clang]
Parsing file /src/ABEnumType.h...
```

Comment: Just wondering, have you tried it with a comma after `StateB`? As far as I can tell, that's the only difference between what I have working and your example.

Comment: @IdoRan almost there. You need to add NS_ENUM(x,y)=enum y

Answer (score 5):

The following settings worked for us:

```
 ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES 
 MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES 
 EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES 
 PREDEFINED             = NS_ENUM(x,y)=enum y
```

With this we see all the NS_ENUM structures showing up in our doxygen generated documentation

Comment: I had to use a slight variation on this: `PREDEFINED = "NS_ENUM(type, name)=enum name"`. My declarations are in the form: `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, NameOfEnum)`

Comment: More accurately, it should be `PREDEFINED = "NS_ENUM(_type, _name)=enum _name : _type"`

Comment: It works for me with following configuration. And our enum must be declare inside class or interface <.h>
`MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES`
`PREDEFINED = "NS_ENUM(_type, _name)=enum _name : _type"`

Answer (score 2):

If Doxygen fails, you can always try [HeaderDocs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/HeaderDoc/intro/intro.html).

EDIT: I tried headerdocs with a test class and I think it does provide good support of NS_ENUM.

```
//
//  VLTTestClass.h
//  VPNLoginTest
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

/*!
 Test class type description.
 */
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, VLTestClassType) {
    /*!
     Description for type 1.
     */
    VLTestClassType1,
    /*!
     Description for type 2.
     */
    VLTestClassType2
};

/*!
 Description for test class
 */
@interface VLTTestClass : NSObject

@end
```

Here is the headerdoc2html:http://pastebin.com/q6RsR0tU

Comment: The funny thing is that HeaderDocs also make a poor job with NS_ENUM. That's why I move to Doxygen :)

Comment: @IdoRan The other option is [AppleDoc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10109496/objective-c-documentation-generators-headerdoc-vs-doxygen-vs-appledoc). Also a useful plugin for Xcode : https://github.com/onevcat/VVDocumenter-Xcode

Comment: Hi, thanks. I've found them both. AppleDoc also does not support NS_ENUM :) try that. I've install VVDocumenter it works great.

Answer (score 2):

[gyurisc's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25500405/218471) answer helped but we also needed to enable `EXTRACT_ALL`. So the following settings work for us:

```
 EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
 ENABLE_PREPROCESSING   = YES 
 MACRO_EXPANSION        = YES 
 EXPAND_ONLY_PREDEF     = YES 
 PREDEFINED             = NS_ENUM(x,y)=enum y
```